# How can I create a reminder on my Apple Watch?

Tags: apple-watch, reminders

I would like to create an iCloud reminder using my Apple Watch while running. Siri is not working and speech recognition is not working either since I'm offline.

Is there an app that allows me to type a reminder?

Comment: I don't think that there would be anything that allows you to create a reminder without using voice dictation.

Answer (score 1):

There's Proud app on the [iTunes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/proud/id891726847?mt=8) where you can create tasks without dictation. It costs 4.99$.

[image: Proud Apple Watch app]